# How to get application's root directory?

Tags: zend-framework2

How do I get application's root directory within an action?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The first thing ZF2 does is to change the current dir via `chdir(dirname(__DIR__));`

This means that every future include is based off of the ROOT PATH of your application and NOT the public folder. Or any other current folder.

Of course this only holds true for PHP-Files.

If you want to define the root path manually, you'd go to `/public/index.php` and add a line like `define('ROOT_PATH', dirname(__DIR__));`

As i said before, for INCLUDES this is NOT required though ;) as you're ALWAYS in the root folder when it comes to PHP-Files ;)

Comment: To add to @Sam's good answer, if you need to know about the url, then use the `RouteMatch` or `Request` objects. They contain all you need to know.

Comment: Is this valid for other path uses? I mean, for example, if I use the chdir method and then want to find a file on the file system for example, can I use relative paths assuming the application root as the current directory?

Comment: @JeroenMoons I don't really understand your question. Basically the current path equals the ZF2-Apps Root. If you change the root via `chdir()` then all PHP Includes will be based off of the path you assign. You can always go up-levels, too via `../`

Comment: I mean, let's say I want to run a command line application on a file, can I provide the relative path to the file based on the application's root folder without problems (the command line application not finding the file)?

Comment: It should be working, depends on how you handle the parameters that you pass within the command line. As long as all will be relative, it should work like a charm.

Comment: @Sam need your help .. my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24949200/page-not-found-on-request-url-in-zend-2-framework-application/24952498

Answer (score 8):

getcwd() works best for me, **DIR** return the module root. Which isn't much use in this case

Answer (score 5):

> @Sam:
>    I don't really understand your question. Basically the current path equals the ZF2-Apps Root. [...] You can always go up-levels, too via ../

Not exactly. When You create module shared within several applications ex. FileUpload Module in vendor, outside application. You would like to upload file to Application subdirectory not shared  module :) In this case `__DIR__` equals module path not app path and `../` wouldn,t be good solution ;)

I like ROOT_PATH as You have mentioned:

> `define('ROOT_PATH', dirname(__DIR__));`

or even better:

```
getcwd()
```

Comment: Nope, `__DIR__` always equals the path of the file it is used in. It never changes.

Comment: Oh, now I understand. This functionality should be configured by the usual config, not brittle constants (which no application is obliged to supply). Else, the whole ZF2 mechanism of flexible configuration doesn't make sense.