# Page not found on request url in zend 2 framework application

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2, zend-db, zend-framework-modules

I am newbie to zend framework and i am trying to configure the zend. I was sucessfully installed zendskeleton applicaion on **window 7** and **XAMPP**

After installation I am creating new module **Album** as per define in user guide. I was make all code and pages according to guide, but after that i was enable to open **Album module**. i got error 404 not found.

here code

1. **application.config**

   ```
    return array(

    'modules' => array(
    'Application','Album',
    ),

   'module_paths' => array(
   './module',
   './vendor',
   ),

   'config_glob_paths' => array(
   'config/autoload/{,*.}{global,local}.php',
    ),

     ),
       );
   ```
2. **module.config**

   ```
    return array(
       'controllers' => array(
        'invokables' => array(
        'Album\Controller\Album' => 'Album\Controller\AlbumController',
        ),
         ),
         'router' => array(
          'routes' => array(
            'album' => array(
             'type' => 'segment',
                'options' => array(
                    'route' => '/album[/][:action][/:id]',
                        'constraints' => array(
                            'action' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                                'id' => '[0-9]+',
                                ),
                                'defaults' => array(
                                    'controller' => 'Album\Controller\Album',
                                        'action' => 'index',
                            ),
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
            ),

                                'view_manager' => array(
                                'template_path_stack' => array(
                                'album' => __DIR__ . '/../view',
                                ),
                           ),
                       );
   ```
3. **Module.php**

   ```
   namespace Album;

    // Add these import statements:
    use Album\Model\Album;
    use Album\Model\AlbumTable;
    use Zend\Db\ResultSet\ResultSet;
    use Zend\Db\TableGateway\TableGateway;

    class Module
    {
     // getAutoloaderConfig() and getConfig() methods here



    // Add this method:
     public function getServiceConfig()
      {
         return array(
         'factories' => array(
         'Album\Model\AlbumTable' => function($sm) {
          $tableGateway = $sm->get('AlbumTableGateway');
          $table = new AlbumTable($tableGateway);
          return $table;
      },
        'AlbumTableGateway' => function ($sm) {
         $dbAdapter = $sm->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter');
         $resultSetPrototype = new ResultSet();
         $resultSetPrototype->setArrayObjectPrototype(new Album());
         return new TableGateway('album', $dbAdapter, null, $resultSetPrototype);
       },
      ),
      );
      }
       }
   ```
4. **httpd-vhosts.conf**

   ```
    <VirtualHost *:81>
    ServerName zf2-tutorial.localhost
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp\htdocs/ZendSkeletonApplication/ZendSkeletonApplication-master/public"
    SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV "development"
    <Directory C:/xampp\htdocs/ZendSkeletonApplication/ZendSkeletonApplication-master/public>
     DirectoryIndex index.php
     AllowOverride All
     Order allow,deny
     Allow from all
     </Directory>
     </VirtualHost>
   ```
5. host entry at **system32**

   ```
     127.0.0.1:8081       zf2-tutorial.localhost
   ```

[image]

How can i handle it.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when you point with your apache document root to `C:/xampp\htdocs/ZendSkeletonApplication/ZendSkeletonApplication-master/public`

you need to use in your browser this url `http://zf2-tutorial.localhost:8081/album` 
and not like you wrote `http://zf2-tutorial.localhost/ZendSkeletonApplication/ZendSkeletonApplication-master/public/album`

this url points internal to a different module/location.

//edit

if this not work check your zf2 `/public` folder if there is a `.htaccess` file present otherwise use the file from the zend skeleton application here https://github.com/zendframework/ZendSkeletonApplication/blob/master/public/.htaccess

please check also your `apache vhost` entry if the `port` is equal to your `windows host` file  port.

make sure apache `ModRewrite` is loaded!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57995/discussion-between-ins0-and-anshul-parashar).

Answer (score 1):

Basic misconfigurations in your setup causes this error.

1. I don't use windows for along time but you're using both forward and backslashes in your paths. Firstly, you should find the correct directory separator for windows and stick with it. This seems problematic: `C:/xampp\htdocs/foo/bar/public`
2. You're defining a virtualhost which listens any IP address on port `81` (*:81), a system32 hosts entry which points to port `8081` as `zf2-tutorial.localhost` alias and trying to call `zf2-tutorial.localhost/album` url using port `80`. Getting this kind of error pretty normal.

After completely reading the official [Getting Started](https://zf2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/user-guide/overview.html) and [Using Apache Web Server](https://zf2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/user-guide/skeleton-application.html#using-the-apache-web-server) documentations, you'll easily figure out the solution.

Comment: i already make changes in `http.conf` file 'allow fileinfo' and 'vhost' file

Answer (score 0):

It seems you missing a vhost entry in your webserver. This could the reason why your application doesn't resolve your request right. Check the "getting startet: A skeleton application" again, to provide a proper configuration.

Comment: thanks for answer. Now i am insert entry into vhost file. when i open "zf2-tutorial.localhost" not webpage found error comes.

Answer (score 0):

You need this hostfile entry. Adding ports is not possible in this file.

```
127.0.0.1 zf2-tutorial.localhost
```

The website is now available at zf2-tutorial.localhost:81 (and not 8081, you set 81 as the portnumber in the first line of httpd-vhosts.conf)

Comment: i make update in `vhosts.conf` still not working. actullay port `80` are used in `tomcat` server thats why i used 81